# R Interpolation of Points on a Cumulative Curve

Tags: r, interpolation

I have the following cumulative cost data ($billions) against different proportions of the population (% covered):

```
test_df <- data.frame(cum.pop = c(0, 8.3, 37.7, 70.5, 90.5, 96.7, 98.7, 100),
                  cum.cost = c(0, 0.7, 3.4, 6.3, 14.1, 22.6, 28.3, 41.9))
```

I want to calculate what percentage of the population is covered by every $2 billion.

EDIT:

A linear fit does not produce the desired result, as the curve is an exponential, as graphed below:
[image]

How do I fit an exponential? AEBilgrau's answer using Approxfun works, but the output does not produce accurate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to fit splines too (although there is a risk of overfitting):

```
library(spline)
ispl <- interpSpline(cum.pop ~ cum.cost,  test_df)

# plots the interpolated spline
plot(ispl)    
points(test_df[,2], test_df[,1], pch=19)
```

[image]

```
cum.cost <- seq(0, 42, 2) # every 2B$
cum.cost
# [1]  0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42
# predicted pop
pred.cum.pop <- predict(ispl, cum.cost)$y
pred.cum.pop
# [1]   0.00000  22.51128  44.72944  67.60543  82.57553  89.24549  90.81892  90.50744  90.98837  92.45519  94.38025  96.23579  97.53846  98.26304  98.65462
#[16]  98.93703  99.17804  99.38472  99.56401  99.72285  99.86816 100.00689

# plots othe predicted cum.pop for each 2B$ rise in cum.cost
plot(ispl)    
points(cum.cost, pred.cum.pop, col='red', pch=19)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "best approach" --- at least not when you do not specify what you mean by "best" and with little information provided. Some approaches are better than others, sure. 
Anyway, I guess that this is not really a programming question then. So you need to decide what approach will fit your requirements and want you want to do.

If you want to do simple linear interpolation (which might or might not be fine for your purposes), you can do something like this

```
 # Load your toy data
 test_df <- data.frame(cum.pop = c(0, 8.3, 37.7, 70.5, 90.5, 96.7, 98.7, 100),
                      cum.cost = c(0, 0.7, 3.4, 6.3, 14.1, 22.6, 28.3, 41.9))

# Create a function that carries out the interpolation
get_pop <- approxfun(x = test_df$cum.cost, y = test_df$cum.pop)

# Call the function for every two billion dollars
get_pop(seq(0, 40, by = 2))
```

This correspons to reading off the plot

```
 plot(cum.pop ~ cum.cost, data = test_df, type = "b")
```

On the face of it, it seems that there is relatively little noise in your data here. So that might be just fine.

Comment: Yes, 'best approach' is very vague AEBilgrau. I've edited the answer to specifically find how to fit to this curve which is exponential. The linear approach worked, but did not produce accurate outputs.